# Web service returns "301 error moved permanently" in production environment

Tags: jquery, web-services, iis, relative-path

I am calling a web service using jQuery, and I have a very strange problem i've had problems with all morning. When I call the web service in my development environment, everything works perfectly. When put into production, I get an "301 Moved Permanently     38ms" from Firebug.

I have my script which is like this:

```
 var data = '{"product":"' + productName + '", "from":"' + from + '", "question":"' +     question + '", "phone":"' + phone + '", "type":"' + typeOfMail + '"}';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    data: data,
    url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Services/MailService.asmx/SendProductEmail") %>',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        resetContactControls();
        $('#<%=AskQuestionProductBtn.ClientID %>').hide();
    },
    failure: function (data) {
    }
});
```

This compiles to the following URL in production:

```
url: '/Services/MailService.asmx/SendProductEmail'
```

In my production environment, with Firebug I can see it tries to reach my URL:

```
http://www.hcemballering.dk/Services/MailService.asmx/SendProductEmail
```

When manually trying to open this URL, I hit my webservice. I've also tried changing the url so it just uses the normal ../Services/MailService.asmx/SendProductEmail .

I've also tried to look at my security settings, and it should work (all processes have access). I even tried to give the user "Everyone" full access to "Services", so it shouldn't be the problem.

This is my web service class:

```
[ScriptService]
public class MailService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MailService));

    [WebMethod]
    public bool SendProductEmail(string product, string from, string question, string phone, string type)
    {
        try
        {

            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

            content.AppendLine(
                string.Format(
                    "Produkt:<br/>{0}<br/><br/>Fra email:<br/>{1}<br/><br/>Telefon:<br/>{2}<br/><br/>Type af henvendelse:<br/>{3}<br/><br/>Spørgsmål:<br/>{4}",
                    product, from, phone, type, question));
            var module = new MailModule(content.ToString(), "Kontakt om HC produkt: " + product);
            module.SendMail();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            throw new Exception("Mailen blev desværre ikke sendt, da der skete en fejl");
        }


        return true;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hold on a second. On another note, are you self-concatenating a JSONified string? You can make it an object literal and pass it to jQuery, and jQuery will take care of stringifying it... *correctly*. (I would recommend not JSONifying yourself.) Spacing it a bit more sanely (as in the fiddle) also helps when you have to try to understand and/or figure out why it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this was silly.

This was caused by a rule in my web.config. I had the following rule:

```
  <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>

          <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
        </rule>
```

And of course, my URL wasn't lower case. So I did this:

```
 <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{URL}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^.+\.((axd)|(js)|(xaml)|(asmx))$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
        </rule>
```

And also made everything lowercase, just because it's good style anyway.

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

You're using GET when you manually hit the web service. You ajax is using POST.  Is your web service set up to receive POST?

Comment: You can see the code. Is there some attribute I need to add? I guess it would work in production if it works in development?

Comment: Looking at the code it's set up for the defaults, which is POST and JSON.  301 means it's redirected.  Are you following all the redirects?

Comment: As far as I know, an AJAX call will always follow the 301, so it should do that